# Slicing XML strings in a safe, Rust way

Tags: xml, unicode, rust, unsafe

I'm working on parsing XML, and we discovered that the XML parser spent a lot of time needlessly checking for UTF compatibility. For example, let's say I'm parsing something akin to:

```xml
<root><ß❤></ß❤></root>
```

In our flamegraphs, we'd spend a lot of time checking whether `root` or `ß❤` was valid UTF.

One way to avoid this check is to have a precondition that XML input is valid Rust `&str`. Since it is and the delimiters are ASCII based, in theory, slicing between any two ASCII delimiters should yield valid &str, which we won't check.

Is this a safe assumption? Or even better, is there a crate that does something similar (e.g. `CSV`)?

Comment: To be clear, you find that when you slice like `data[i..j]`, the application spends a lot of time checking that `i` and `j` are UTF-8 code point boundaries, and you want to avoid that check? Or are you talking about a slightly different scenario?

Comment: @trentcl see issue here https://github.com/servo/html5ever/issues/286 in essence tokenizers works on `char`s, chars are `u32` Unicode scalar value, and pulling chars out of a UTF-8 slice in a safe manner causes overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine that most XML parsers will check for valid UTF-8 encoding at the level of the input stream as a whole, and will then do further checks at a higher level that "root" and "ß❤" are valid XML names. You're certainly right to observe that these checks can be costly and that there are opportunities for optimization; and that one of these opportunities might be to take advantage of the fact that UTF-8 encoding principles ensure that the octet x3C never occurs in a UTF-8 stream except as a representation of the character "<".

You can also reduce the cost of parsing by cutting out some of the checks altogether. A parser that doesn't detect all errors isn't conformant with W3C standards, but that doesn't make it useless. However, beware of getting obsessed with performance at the expense of everything else: for 95% of your users, producing good error messages is probably worth at least a 10% performance overhead.